# How to change background animation of a MenuFlyout?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, animation, windows-phone-8.1

I'm searching for a way to change the animation of a MenuFlyout in WP 8.1. If a MenuFlyout is opened, the content in the background kind of zooms out and gets darker. I couldn't find this in the generic.xaml, so I'm wondering where to find the implementation and how to change it.

Comment: Have you found a way to do this?

Comment: No I'm sorry, I just changed my app so that I can avoid the MenuFlyout. Don't have enough time to do hours of researching :/